# Rube Goldberg, twisting in a lightbulb

Tags: mechanical-engineering, lighting

For my rube golberg project I have to twist a lightbulb in and have it turn on. I have seen different videos on how they do it but they never explain it and most of the videos are blurry. We can't have the lightbulb already in partway to screw it in.   Does anyone know what the best way to have something screw the lightbulb in and a great power source for it to turn on?

Comment: Hold the bulb and rotate the rest...

Comment: If there was a battery and LED inside the (frosted) envelope, you would only need a switch on the end of the bulb.